# Is it correct to say "<language A> is written in <language B>?"

Tags: interpreter

If we have a language, say "Foo", and it's (only) interpreter is written in C, we could of course say:

"The Foo interpreter is written in C"

However, would it make sense to shorten this to:

"Foo is written in C"

I found this example on a Wikipedia page discussing a language and I feel like this second sentence is ambiguous and confusing enough to be incorrect.

Thoughts?

Comment: Has been implemented using C language

Comment: That would make sense to me, but what about "Foo is written in C"?

Comment: Well, if there happens to be another translator like a compiler, "interpreter " might be a  essential qualifier. One program keeps no constraints over the other.

Comment: It does not really make sense to say "Foo is written in C". A casual observer might construe this to mean "Use C when writing Foo". This is obviously incorrect.